# Align table side by side with graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to get my csv table aligned to the left of my graph. The graph is appearing below (and indented) the table. Any ideas?

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
columns/distance/.style={column name={Col1}, column type={|c|}},
columns/loss/.style={column name = {Col2},column type={c|}},
every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
after row={\hline}
]{graph-data/data.csv}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel = Distance ($m$),
ylabel = Loss ($dB$)]
\addplot table [col sep=comma]{graph-data/data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Does the problem still arise if you set the width of each `minipage` to `0.45\textwidth`?

Comment: Don't leave a blank line in between. It amounts to a new paragraph. Also put a `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` like `\end{minipage}%`.

Comment: Yes, in fact the width setting seems to have no effect on the output whatsoever. Even if I set it to 0.1, it doesn't alter anything.

Comment: @HarishKumar that's it! Stupid stupid Latex! Seriously, on one level it's **such** a good tool but it takes _way_ too long to do the basics!

Answer (score 1):

As Harish Kumar says, the blank line between the `minipages` causes a new paragraph to start, in particular you get the second minipage placed in a newline.  He also says you should add a `%` after the first `\end{minipage}`; this would mean no extra horizontal space is inserted between the two `minipages`.  However, usually it is better to add some space to make sure they do not butt up against each other, you can add this with `\hspace{1cm}` or I prefer `\quad`.

Either way the sum of you widths should be smaller than the total `\textwidth`, to allow for the extra space around the environments.  Additionally you should set the width of your plot to fit within its column:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
distance,loss
10,1
12,5
13,8
15,9
20,10
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, columns/distance/.style={column
  name={Distance}, column type={|c|}}, columns/loss/.style={column name =
  {Loss},column type={c|}}, every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
  after row={\hline} ]{data.csv}
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth, xlabel = Distance ($m$), ylabel = Loss ($dB$)]
      \addplot table [col sep=comma]{data.csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Of course it would be usual to put such a combination in `center` environment or a float.